# Data Binding WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF. can any one please let me know how data binding works? and please help me for the following code I want to assign this Name property to text box or text block can anybody help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;           
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace MyFirstExample.ViewModel
{
    class ViewModelAdd: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


  private   String m_Name = "Hello";



        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Name;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Read all the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) yet? Also your question is too broad, one could write half a book about data-binding.

Comment: hey Mate I just want to add this name property to text box means I just want to set text={Binding Name} but m not able to do that

Comment: Heard of `DataContext`? Also this question has been asked ad nauseam...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy as @H.B suggest go through the msdn references to know more about DataBinding. But here just to solve your problem, you will have to set the DataContext for your window to this ViewModel instance. I dont know about UI code, but if in constructor of your window you do

```
ViewModelAdd vm = new ViewModelAdd();
DataContext = vm;
```

this should work.

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks mate. It was helpful. I just wanted to know I edited the App.xaml.cs And did overriding of the starting point with the method Onstartup but I am getting two starting windows. can you help mate?